# Faulty Price Is Right program

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

Here's the requirements:

> Write a method called priceIsRight that mimics the guessing rules from the game show 'The Price     is Right'. The method accepts as parameters an array of integers representing the contestants' bids and an integer representing a correct price. The method returns the element in the bids array that 
>   is closest in value to the correct price without being larger than that price.

Here's my method:

```
public static int priceisRight(int[] bids, int price){
   int closest = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < bids.length; i++){
      if(closest < bids[i] && bids[i] <= price)
          closest=bids[i];
      }
   }
   return closest;
   }
}
```

The error message I keep getting is:

> illegal start of type, ';' expected, and class, interface, or enum expected.

I've looked over it a dozen times and I really just don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: Missing a `{` after your if statement line? Extra `}` at the end?

Comment: Wowwwwwwwwwwww okay so the error was me xD Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int priceisRight(int bids[], int price)
{
   int closest = 0;
   for(int i=0; i< bids.length; i++)
   {
      if(closest<bids[i] && bids[i]<=price)
      {
        closest=bids[i];
      }
   }
   return closest;
}
```

Works fine for me, you've just missed the brace.
I usually write the braces below the line so i can see them match each other.
Also if you put that in notepad++ and go with the cursor to the position of the brace you'll see its counterpart. Remember the compiler usually always shows the error the line above, because it's reading your source backwards.

Comment: @DanielWu I've included some more info what you can do to avoid these kind of mistakes.